# Trying To Display A LinearLayout With Three Button Below A ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have been trying to display three buttons namely; Share, Mingle, Rating which are enclosed in Linear Layout below, a ListView. When I run my solution, the three buttons do not display on the device but the ListView displays.

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layoutthreebuttons" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="1dp" android:background="@color/blue2" android:textColor="@color/white" android:text="SHARE" />
    <Button android:layout_marginRight="1dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@color/blue2" android:textColor="@color/white" android:text="MINGLE" />
    <Button android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@color/blue2" android:textColor="@color/white" android:text="RATINGS" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" android:layout_above="@+id/layoutthreebuttons" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just tried your code and I don't see any error, the display is OK, maybe give more details

Comment: I want the three buttons to display on the device, the buttons show in the graphical layout but when I run my solution, the buttons are not displayed on the device screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I just implemented the solution above, still facing the same problem. All the Listview elements are displayed, but the three buttons are  not displayed on the device screen.

Comment: I agree with this solution however he was asking using a RelativeLayout therefore the reply should still use a RelativeLayout and not a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

When you tell your ListView to be above your buttons, and the ListView uses full screen size, then it will not work. Just try it without.

Answer (score 0):

[image: result]

Add `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` to the listview's definition:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutthreebuttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blue2"
        android:text="SHARE"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blue2"
        android:text="MINGLE"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blue2"
        android:text="RATINGS"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layoutthreebuttons" >
</ListView>
```